# phpMyAdmin create a trigger for deleting a parent row when no child rows exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin I have two tables: listings and textbooks. listings has a foreign key (isbn) from textbooks. I'm trying to create a trigger which, after an entry from listings is deleted, checks to see if there are any other rows in listings with the same isbn as the row that was deleted. If there are no rows with this isbn, then the row with that isbn in textbooks is deleted. This is the code I've tried in phpMyAdmin:

```
CREATE TRIGGER del_textbook AFTER DELETE ON listings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listings WHERE isbn = (OLD.isbn)) > 0
    DELETE FROM textbooks WHERE isbn = (OLD.isbn);
END IF;
END;
```

It gives this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM textbooks WHERE isbn = (OLD.isbn); END IF; END' at line 5
```

I also set the delimiter to // before executing this.

Can anybody tell me if my code is formatted correctly, or why this error is occurring? I know that phpmyAdmin is kind of finicky with its formatting. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. First of all, don't use the SQL query window. Use the Triggers tab. I also forgot the "THEN", so the code looks like:

```
BEGIN
     IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listings WHERE isbn = OLD.isbn) < 1) THEN
     DELETE FROM textbooks WHERE isbn = OLD.isbn;
     END IF;
END
```